# How to store products in a session

Tags: php

I want to store multiple items in a cart using sessions, thats not too hard, I know. But every item can have extra's. Like a pizza hawaii can have extra ananas. But you cant order the extra ananas without the pizza only as an 'extra'.

Does someone have a good tutorial or example, every product needs an own array since you can also have 1 pizza hawaii with extra ananas and one without. I couldn't find any good tutorial on how to do this.

BTW, a pizza can have more than one extra.

Thanks in advance guys!!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: if you know how sessions, arrays and if/else structures work, it shouldn't be that hard.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are using javascript, you can do it like this

```
sessionStorage.setItem('extra', 'Pizza');
/* Returns null if it cannot find the item in sessionStorage. */
if(sessionStorage.getItem('extra')) {
    /* Session storage set successfully. */
    /* Do whatever you like to do. */
} else {
    /* Session storage did not set successfully. */
    /* Do whatever you like to do. */
}
```